# How inject an EntityManager to a EJB? What is wrong in this situation?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, ejb

I am trying to run a web application on Glassfish Server. When my DAO is coded like this I have no problems on my test page. I can get all the customers and see them on the datatable.

```
@Stateful
public class CustomersDao {

    static EntityManagerFactory emf;
    static EntityManager em;

    public List<Customers> getAllCustomers() {

        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Persistence");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();

        TypedQuery<Customers> query = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Customers c", Customers.class);

        List<Customers> allCustomers = query.getResultList();

        System.out.println(allCustomers);
        System.out.println(allCustomers.get(0).getCountry());

        return allCustomers;
    }
}
```

However, when I change the class to:

```
@Stateful
public class CustomersDao {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "Persistence")
    EntityManager em;

    public List<Customers> getAllCustomers() {


        TypedQuery<Customers> query = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Customers c", Customers.class);

        List<Customers> allCustomers = query.getResultList();

        System.out.println(allCustomers);
        System.out.println(allCustomers.get(0).getCountry());

        return allCustomers;
    }

}
```

I am getting: **javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: Persistence] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory**

**|Exception while preparing the app : [PersistenceUnit: Persistence] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Connection cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set**

Here is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="Persistence">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>com.tugay.maythirty.model.Customers</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sampleapplication"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="passsssss"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Any help?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="Persistence">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/classicmodels</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.tugay.maythirty.model.Customers</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first snippet an *Application-Managed Entity Manager* is used. When you inject the Entity Manager using `@PersistenceContext`, this will be a *Container-Managed Entity Manager*, which needs a JTA data source. So you should create a data source within the Glassfish Server, say named `myJtaDataSource`, then your `persistence.xml` should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="Persistence">
        <jta-data-source>myJtaDataSource</jta-data-source>
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>com.tugay.maythirty.model.Customers</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Take a look at here for creating a data source with Glassfish:
http://itsolutionsforall.com/datasource_jpa.php

Comment: If I keep everything in <properties> tags, are they overriden?

Comment: How can I do this with Tomcat server ?